Could not create or update Cloud Run service handlestripewebhook, Container Healthcheck failed
Trying to deploy firebase functions with a Stripe webhook with Svelte5. I set the secrets:
firebase functions:secrets:get STRIPE_SECRET_KEY    
firebase functions:secrets:get STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET

And have my minimal code in functions/src/index.ts
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { defineSecret } from 'firebase-functions/params';
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import Stripe from 'stripe';

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp();

// Define secrets using defineSecret
const stripeSecretKey = defineSecret('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY');
const stripeWebhookSecret = defineSecret('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET');

// Simplified handleStripeWebhook function
export const handleStripeWebhook = onRequest(
  { secrets: [stripeSecretKey, stripeWebhookSecret], cors: true },
  async (req, res) => {
    const stripe = new Stripe(stripeSecretKey.value());

    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    let event;

    try {
      const body = req.rawBody.toString();
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, stripeWebhookSecret.value());
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Webhook Error: ${(err as Error).message}`);
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${(err as Error).message}`);
      return;
    }

    // Log the event for troubleshooting
    console.log(`Received event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

    res.json({ received: true });
  }
);

But get to this annoying error message which doesnt really tell me anything
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function handleStripeWebhook(us-central1)...
Could not create or update Cloud Run service handlestripewebhook, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'handlestripewebhook-00012-qar' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short. The health check timeout can be extended. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=XXXX&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/handlestripewebhook/revision_name/handlestripewebhook-00012-qar&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook-00012-qar%22 
For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        handleStripeWebhook(XXXXX)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/XXXX/us/gcf

Error: There was an error deploying functions

I've tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling functions - seems like the only thread with answers. I've destroyed and re-entered my secrets. Nothing works for now.
EDIT:
Error 1
{
  "textPayload": "Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container \"worker\" on port 8080. The instance was not started.",
  "insertId": "6758d8180000a03441679b15",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "revision_name": "handlestripewebhook-00012-qar",
      "service_name": "handlestripewebhook",
      "configuration_name": "handlestripewebhook",
      "location": "REDACTED_LOCATION",
      "project_id": "REDACTED_PROJECT_ID"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-12-11T00:08:56.041012Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
    "instanceId": "REDACTED_INSTANCE_ID"
  },
  "logName": "projects/REDACTED_PROJECT_ID/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-12-11T00:08:56.295019255Z"
}

Error 2
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 9,
      "message": "Ready condition status changed to False for Revision handlestripewebhook-00012-qar with message: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short. The health check timeout can be extended. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=PROJECT_ID&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/handlestripewebhook/revision_name/handlestripewebhook-00012-qar&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook-00012-qar%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start"
    },
    "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "/InternalServices.ReplaceInternalService",
    "resourceName": "namespaces/PROJECT_ID/revisions/handlestripewebhook-00012-qar",
    "response": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "handlestripewebhook-00012-qar",
        "namespace": "PROJECT_NAMESPACE",
        "selfLink": "/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/PROJECT_NAMESPACE/revisions/handlestripewebhook-00012-qar",
        "uid": "REDACTED_UID",
        "resourceVersion": "REDACTED_VERSION",
        "generation": 1,
        "creationTimestamp": "2024-12-11T00:08:23.090699Z",
        "labels": {
          "serving.knative.dev/configuration": "handlestripewebhook",
          "serving.knative.dev/configurationGeneration": "12",
          "serving.knative.dev/service": "handlestripewebhook",
          "serving.knative.dev/serviceUid": "REDACTED_UID",
          "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
          "goog-cloudfunctions-runtime": "nodejs18",
          "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "us-central1",
          "serving.knative.dev/route": "handlestripewebhook",
          "run.googleapis.com/startupProbeType": "Default"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "run.googleapis.com/client-name": "cloudfunctions",
          "run.googleapis.com/startup-cpu-boost": "true",
          "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/trigger-type": "HTTP_TRIGGER",
          "run.googleapis.com/secrets": "secret-REDACTED:projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET,secret-REDACTED:projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/STRIPE_SECRET_KEY",
          "run.googleapis.com/build-source-location": "{\"worker\":\"gs://gcf-v2-sources-PROJECT_ID-us-central1/handleStripeWebhook/function-source.zip#REDACTED\"}",
          "serving.knative.dev/creator": "service-PROJECT_ID@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
          "run.googleapis.com/build-function-target": "{\"worker\":\"handleStripeWebhook\"}",
          "run.googleapis.com/base-images": "{\"worker\":\"us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/serverless-runtimes/google-22-full/runtimes/nodejs18\"}",
          "run.googleapis.com/build-id": "{\"worker\":\"REDACTED\"}",
          "run.googleapis.com/launch-stage": "BETA",
          "run.googleapis.com/operation-id": "REDACTED",
          "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale": "100"
        },
        "ownerReferences": [
          {
            "kind": "Configuration",
            "name": "handlestripewebhook",
            "uid": "REDACTED_UID",
            "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
            "controller": true,
            "blockOwnerDeletion": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
      "kind": "Revision",
      "spec": {
        "containerConcurrency": 80,
        "timeoutSeconds": 60,
        "serviceAccountName": "PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "worker",
            "image": "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/gcf-artifacts/PROJECT_ID__us--central1__handle_stripe_webhook@sha256:REDACTED",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http1",
                "containerPort": 8080
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "BLA_SENDGRID_KEY",
                "value": "REDACTED"
              },
              {
                "name": "BLA_ENDGRID_TEMPLATE",
                "value": "REDACTED"
              },
              {
                "name": "FIREBASE_CONFIG",
                "value": "{\"projectId\":\"PROJECT_ID\",\"storageBucket\":\"PROJECT_ID.firebasestorage.app\"}"
              },
              {
                "name": "GCLOUD_PROJECT",
                "value": "PROJECT_ID"
              },
              {
                "name": "EVENTARC_CLOUD_EVENT_SOURCE",
                "value": "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/services/handleStripeWebhook"
              },
              {
                "name": "FUNCTION_TARGET",
                "value": "handleStripeWebhook"
              },
              {
                "name": "LOG_EXECUTION_ID",
                "value": "true"
              },
              {
                "name": "STRIPE_SECRET_KEY",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "key": "2",
                    "name": "secret-REDACTED"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "key": "2",
                    "name": "secret-REDACTED"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "1",
                "memory": "256Mi"
              }
            },
            "startupProbe": {
              "timeoutSeconds": 240,
              "periodSeconds": 240,
              "failureThreshold": 1,
              "tcpSocket": {
                "port": 8080
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "runtimeClassName": "run.googleapis.com/linux-base-image-update"
      },
      "status": {
        "observedGeneration": 1,
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "Ready",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short. The health check timeout can be extended. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=PROJECT_ID&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/handlestripewebhook/revision_name/handlestripewebhook-00012-qar&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook-00012-qar%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-12-11T00:08:56.042205Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "ContainerHealthy",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short. The health check timeout can be extended. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=PROJECT_ID&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/handlestripewebhook/revision_name/handlestripewebhook-00012-qar&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook-00012-qar%22",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-12-11T00:08:56.042205Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "ContainerReady",
            "status": "True",
            "message": "Container image import completed in 5.970382s.",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-12-11T00:08:29.856747Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "ResourcesAvailable",
            "status": "True",
            "message": "Revision deployment finished in 23.73708s. Checking container health.",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-12-11T00:08:53.590376Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Retry",
            "status": "True",
            "reason": "ImmediateRetry",
            "message": "System will retry after 0:00:00 from lastTransitionTime for attempt 0.",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-12-11T00:08:53.590376Z",
            "severity": "Info"
          }
        ],
        "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=PROJECT_ID&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/handlestripewebhook/revision_name/handlestripewebhook-00012-qar&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22handlestripewebhook-00012-qar%22",
        "imageDigest": "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/gcf-artifacts/PROJECT_ID__us--central1__handle_stripe_webhook@sha256:REDACTED",
        "containerStatuses": [
          {
            "name": "worker",
            "imageDigest": "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/gcf-artifacts/PROJECT_ID__us--central1__handle_stripe_webhook@sha256:REDACTED"
          }
        ]
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.run.v1.Revision"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "umk9de28fhw",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "service_name": "handlestripewebhook",
      "revision_name": "handlestripewebhook-00012-qar",
      "project_id": "PROJECT_ID",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "configuration_name": "handlestripewebhook"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-12-11T00:08:56.052959Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-12-11T00:08:56.435853493Z"
}


The error message told you where to go to see some logs.  What did you find there?  Please edit the question to share those details.

@DougStevenson Updated it

So I made the biggest blunder of all - I noticed via firebase deploy --only functions --debug that I didn't have stripe installed. So npm i stripe in my functions folder and all good to go.
